# Cannot center tikz Cayley graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to horizontally center the Cayley graph given by the code below, but I haven't had any luck. I can get it pretty close to centered by manipulating the spacing with `\vspace` and `\hspace`, but that isn't ideal. Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
     \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}
     \usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
      \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{cayley}{
        \rule{F -> F [ R [F] [+F] [-F] ]}
        \symbol{R}{
        \pgflsystemstep=0.5\pgflsystemstep
        } 
      }

\begin{document}
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   %\vspace{1cm}
   %\hspace{.75cm}
   \begin{centering}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
      \draw l-system [l-system={cayley, axiom=[F] [+F] [-F] [++F], step=5cm, order=6}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{centering}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! `\begin{center}...\end{center}` or `\centering`. Though I doubt this is the issue. Please complete your code so we can compile it.

Answer (score 1):

Image cannot be centered because it is too big for the page, so you must scale it to .5, or more. This is individual and depends on your image. Also, you can use `begin{center}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
     \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}
     \usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
      \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{cayley}{
        \rule{F -> F [ R [F] [+F] [-F] ]}
        \symbol{R}{
        \pgflsystemstep=0.5\pgflsystemstep
        } 
      }

\begin{document}
   \thispagestyle{empty}

   \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
      \draw l-system [l-system={cayley, axiom=[F] [+F] [-F] [++F], step=5cm, order=6}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```